# Graph of equilibrium constant vs 1/T

Tags: equilibrium

[image]

I have a problem with the 1st option, I did  
$\Delta G = -RTlog(Kp(RT)^{\Delta n})$  
$\Delta H - T\Delta S = -RTlog(Kp(RT)^{\Delta n})$  
$log(Kp) = \frac{\Delta S}{R} - \Delta nlog(RT) - \frac{\Delta H}{RT}$

Here, log(Kp) vs 1 / T isn't linear because of that log term that contains T, but the answer key states that that option is correct
[image]

This would be the case if it were Keq vs 1 / T instead(or $\Delta n = 0$, but nothing is stated).
 Did they intend for it to be Keq or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why are you converting to Kc? The equation with $\Delta G$ is only valid for Keq, which for a reaction with gases is the same as Kp, not Kc.

Comment: ohhhh, so for gases 'Keq' directly stands for Kp, I thought the equation always holds true with Kc regardless of reactants because 'nature doesn't know that the reactants are gases, so it wont just suddenly follow a different definition for Keq'

Comment: It's slightly more complicated but you have the idea. Keq is a unitless quantity that comes from the "activities" of each reactant, which are defined relative to a standard state of 1 bar for gases, 1 M for solutes and 1 for solids and bulk liquids. You have to reference those standard states because that is the reference point for $\Delta G$